# Get real time data from excel

Tags: php, excel, real-time

Is it possible to get a RTD(real time data) of excel (xlsm) using php (phpspreadsheet)?  if not, what programming language or other method can get the RTD of excel every time it changes?

Comment: yes, phpspreadsheet is very powerful and you can easily read your excel files that changed

Comment: @BehzadGhanadi not possible, it just getting the default value of that excel but not the Real Time Data